# What Verbs can Gerunds Follow?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, word-usage, sentence, gerunds

Throughout my life, I have relied on intuition to ensure that my sentences are intelligible and grammatical. I like using gerunds because they can shorten sentences and avoid redundancy. Recently, however, the use of gerunds in some scenarios has confused me. In a sentence like:

> Francesco Petrarch was a seminal Renaissance humanist who **pioneered unearthing** classical texts.

Would the use of gerunds be grammatical? Or should it be changed to:

> Francesco Petrarch was a seminal Renaissance humanist who pioneered **the unearthing of** classical texts.

Which I often find in fustian or archaic text. Moreover, if the gerund is used correctly in the first sentence, are there rules that govern the use of gerunds?

Comment: Yes, there are rules, but most of them say "it depends on the verb". Some verbs, like sense verbs, can take either infinitive or gerund (_I watched him eat it/eating it_), some take only infinitives, some take only gerunds, some don't take any untensed clauses, and some don't take clause complements at all. A good dictionary should tell you all this for every verb. But most don't.

Comment: @JohnLawyer Interesting. Having lived in an environment where I often use English, I generally have no problem recognizing whether a word can take gerunds by gauging if it sounds natural. However, pioneered + unearthing is unfamiliar territory because I don't remember seeing them anywhere, and I've only used it because I like to avoid using "the + verb-ing + of" construction.

Comment: That's the right attitude. If you have instincts about what sounds right, follow them. There will always be a few that are new.

Comment: @JohnLawler But you can't say "I watched eating it", it has to be "I watched the eating of it", right? The subject of the dependent clause makes a difference.

Comment: There are a lot of differences between _I want to do it, I want him to do it, I promised to do it,_ and _I promised him  to do  it_. For instance. Those pronouns are not just sitting there; they have parts to play in the syntax.

Comment: There are about 15 times as many hits in a Google search for "pioneered the making" (240 000) as there are in one for "pioneered making". I wouldn't label the latter 'incorrect', but neither would I use it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is likely best to appeal to the wisdom of the crowd. [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pioneered+making%2Cpioneered+the+making&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests that "pioneered making" and "pioneered the making" are about equally common at present. Clicking on the Google Books results in Ngram shows many uses of "pioneer" with either a gerund or a verbal noun.